# How to do something like "is_atomically_assignable"?

Tags: c++, c++11, x86, x86-64, atomic

Of course, there's no such thing in std, but I need equivalent functionality.

I have a lock-free data structure templated on a type T, where T is provided by the user, and what I need to statically assert is that T is a type that is atomically assignable on x86 or x86-64 (which includes all built-in integral constants and floating point types, and any typedef thereof, but I think is not necessarily limited to those). I'm guessing that merely checking that the type is trivially assignable and that its sizeof is <= 8 is not sufficient. What's the best way to do this? Forcing T to be an std::atomic<> and then checking is_lock_free() is out of the question.

Comment: Why do you want to use built-in types instead of `std::atomic`? Do you know that the behaviour of the program is undefined, if there is a _data race_ on a built-in type?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I remember small size of data not enough for atomic, additionally data must be aligned.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a traits class, or how to provide specializations of that traits class for built-in types in a reasonably generic fashion?

Comment: _"Forcing T to be an std::atomic<> and then checking is_lock_free() is out of the question."_  What about allowing `T` to be anything, and checking `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()`?

Comment: @MichaelUrman either option.

Comment: @DrewDormann I only care that loads and stores are atomic, not any of the other operations, and atomic without locked CPU instruction (i.e., regular loads and stores of integers, floats etc. on x86(-64) CPUs). I'm not completely sure whether the invariant you propose I check for T is idempotent to my requirement for T.

Answer (score 2):

"atomically assignable" is not sufficient condition for using a type to implement a lock-free data structure, so this idea is going down to the wrong path from the start.

Using `std::atomic` (and friends) is the only way in C++ to have both the atomicity *and the ordering guarantees* necessary to implement a lock-free data structure. Atomic assignment is useless if no other thread will ever see it.

Comment: Absolutely wrong about it being a sufficient condition. It's a sufficient condition in various algorithms, such as http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1824.pdf Refer to Fig.3. Loads and stores of "data" need to be atomic, and that's it (same for pread and pwrite, but they're not user-supplied so that's besides the point -- the type T in my question is this "data").

Comment: It is not a sufficient condition in C++. C++ doesn't guarantee that those loads and stores load the right data unless the loads and stores are ordered.

Comment: The language doesn't define the problem requirements--the problem does! If the standard structures in the language are a poor fit, how is that a fault of the requirements? That's a ludicrous proposition. If std atomic doesn't solve the problem, then I need an alternate solution--obviously.

Comment: Unless the problem requirements allow *anything to happen*, the problem requirements cannot be met in C++ this way, because C++ allows *anything to happen* if you read and write concurrently to memory locations without an ordering between the two operations.

Comment: C++ may allow anything to happen, but we program for real machines, and specific target architectures provide additional guarantees. For example, my question explicitly notes I only care about x86/x86-64, and I'm looking for the best solution _to my circumstances_, not an absolutely general solution in a world of Platonic mathematical absolutes.

Comment: If I made the types used std atomic and did loads and stores with memory_order_relaxed, there is still overhead as at least in the Visual C++ implementation it inserts compiler barriers (even though it doesn't insert any hardware barriers). This means use of std atomic in this case prevents compiler reordering optimizations, even though the algorithm in that paper only requires any sort of reqordering to be prevented at a single point in the program, where there's an explicit store fence.

Comment: You may want to also restrict to some specific compiler and version, then. Architecture is not enough if you don't know what is generating code for that architecture.

Comment: Worse, elsewhere on this site, and in C++11 articles, I've seen it specified that memory_order_relaxed should never be mixed with other memory orders on the same variables. Since the barrier in said algorithm would in C++ be atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release) that is, in essence, contravening said advice (specification?). PS @RMartinhoFernandes though generalities are useful pedagogically, I came here looking for a practical solution that is also minimally offensive in terms of abusing language standards.